# PHP: file_exists always returns FALSE

Tags: php, file, exists

### Background:

I am trying to make PDF files available to my users but not others. The suggestion seems to be to put these above site root but below web root. The first step is to test that the file exists and the result is always FALSE.
Question: Why does file_exists always return false?
Things tried
 1. created directory called "a" (to avoid misspelling) in web root.
file_exists("/a/") is false
file_exists("/a/info.pdf") is false although the file exists
 2. clearstatcache(); before file_exists
 3. added allow_url_fopen = on to php.ini in root

```
enter code here

  clearstatcache();  
  $full_path = '/a/info.pdf';  // absolute physical path to file below web root.
  if ( file_exists($full_path) )
     {
     $mimetype = 'application/pdf';

     header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
     header('Cache-Control: no-store');
     header('Pragma: no-cache');
     header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype);
     header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($full_path));

     $fh = fopen($full_path,"rb");
     while (!feof($fh)) { print(fread($fh, filesize($full_path))); }
     fclose($fh);
     }
   else die("File does not exist on the server - .");
```

The else is always followed.
What else can I try?

Comment: `file_exists()` uses absolute file paths for the file system rather than web root.

Answer (score 0):

First you must read document of [file_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

If you didn't find your mistake, then check folder files with [scandir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

For example:

```
print_r(scandir('/a/'));
```

Then you can see your file isn't there.

Your problem maybe one of this:

1. Problem in path
2. Problem in file Name

Comment: scandir() does not see the directory either. Mode is 755 for both directory and files within.

Comment: @lain so your problem is in your path route, get your direct file path with [__DIR__](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: The code presented has most variables removed and the file names simplified. I am looking to open file /a/info.pdf where the path starts from root. FileZilla sees the file (it made it!) but file_exists does not.

Comment: @Iain ftp path is different from your php path code, for example maybe your ftp main path is /Iain/public_html/ so your file address is /Iain/public_html/a/info.pdf

Comment: I am surprised that a mainstream function like file_exists() gives the wrong result for reasons which cannot be explained even after many hours of research. I abandoned placing files above root and, instead, put them all (PDFs included) into a database to achieve security that way.

Answer (score 0):

when you use full path like you did **/a/file.pdf**, actually you trying to get file from the root folder of entire server, and not the DOCUMENT_ROOT of you account in the server.

for example:

you have account and the public folder is:

```
/home/{ACCOUNT_NAME}/public_html/index.php
```

so when you trying "/a/file.pdf" you **don't** get :

```
/home/{ACCOUNT_NAME}/a/file.pdf
```

you need to define and check by absolute path in you account only,

for example as i wrote, use full path with you account:

```
/home/{ACCOUNT_NAME}/a/file.pdf
```

or even use relative path if you trying from index.php file:

```
../a/file.pdf
```

if you don't know the full path to your account,

see what you have in :  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  variable

Comment: Thank you shushu304. This solves the problem completely. FileZilla shows the document root as / and I made wrong assumptions from there.

Answer (score 0):

file_exists will also return false if you add a querystring to the end of the filename.

People very often append a randomly generated value to the end of an image filename to ensure the browser does not get the image from cache (in case a new image  with the same name was just uploaded).

For example, if your file name is "*images/staff/staff1.jpg*"

```
file_exists("images/staff/staff1.jpg") // Returns true
file_exists("images/staff/staff1.jpg?21545884")  // Returns false
```

An img tag would accept either string as valid, but file_exists is more picky.